# Named JPA query with wrong return type of size

Tags: java, jpa, integer, long-integer, return-type

I have the following query:

```
select lect from Lecturer lect
where lect.lectures.size > :minNr
```

and this line from a test fills in the value for minNr:

```
query.setParameter("minNr", 2L);
```

My Problem is that I always get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer]
```

If I change the above test line to

```
query.setParameter("minNr", 2);
```

there is no problem. But I must not change the test, because it is an assignment.

Is there any way to cast the return of size to a Long?
Or does count() return a value of type Long?

Hope you understand my problem.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I've used

```
Select count(distinct lecture) FROM Lecture join ...
```

to solve this task. It works fine now.